# How to make Flask run function in HTML and print out the result on the same page?

Tags: python, html, flask

I've been trying to use my script that I previously written to turn Arabic numerals to Roman. User inputs numbers and my script turns them to Roman ones. Script runs fine, but me trying to embed it to a webpage is not working as intended. I googled solutions to that and everyone tell I need to get the value from a form, which I did:

```
                <form action="toroman" method="POST">
                    <input type="number" name="arabic" onChange="toroman(this.value)" oninput="toroman(this.value)">
                    <p>{{ romanfinal }}</p>
                </form>
```

And this is my server.py that should be printing out the number of the same page, but it doesn't do that, instead when I press "Enter" when submitting the value it creates a new page and displays correct answer.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/toroman", methods=['POST'])
def toroman():
    arabic = request.form['arabic']
    # some unnecessarily numerous lines of code that basically turn Arabic-system number to Roman system
    return romanfinal


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is like the only time it actually worked, when I try to change it so something else, it just gives me errors. Please tell me what exactly I don't understand about it.

Comment: Is that you want your translation to show on the index page, and not on an newly created page?

Comment: Correct. And I also want it to do it on-the-fly, and by that I mean <input onChange>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FLASK

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
    def index():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/toroman", methods=['POST'])
def toroman():
    arabic = request.data['arabic']
    #pass arabic into your translation function
    translation = translate()
    #return JSON response to AJAX
    return jsonify(translation = translation)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById('toroman_form').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/toroman', //flask route to which data is sent
        data: $('#arabic').val(), // input field value
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            translation = data.translation //response received from flask
            $('#translated').text(translation) //display translation in html <p> tag
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Transaction Failed");
      }
  });
});
}
```

> HTML

```
<form id="toroman_form">
    <input type="number" id="arabic">
    <p id="translated"><!--translation is dislayed here--></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me. Nothing happens on the index page, and if I press enter it says "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: With `methods=['POST']` in `@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])` the index page wouldn't even load. Without it it would load but the translation still doesn't work :c sorry

Comment: Adjusted it. I've removed the form method in the html.

Comment: I worked on it some more and noticed on the server logs that it always error ```BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'arabic'"```
I tried changing some code but it awlays like that. THEN I changed this line ```arabic = request.form['arabic']``` to ```arabic = request.data``` and printed out data to see. Script runs fine and even displays Error in <p> tags. But that because requested data is ```b'1'``` if I for examle input "1" in the form field. So how to get clean data?

Comment: I did it inside the script, stripping raw data from ```b``` and ```'``` so it's just a number. Thanks for help tho.

Answer (score 1):

Your `toroman():` function should return index.html with the parameter :

```
@app.route("/toroman", methods=['POST'])
def toroman():
    arabic = request.form['arabic']
    # some unnecessarily numerous lines of code that basically turn Arabic-system number to Roman system
    return render_template("index.html", data = romanfinal)
```

Then you can use the value `data` in your HTML top level like that : `{{data}}`

Comment: It works, thanks! But while we're at it. Is there a way to do it on the same page without making whole "/toroman" thing? And it only workd on "Enter" press, is there a way to do it onChange?

Comment: I think this is possible, maybe with ```'GET'``` request, but I have never used it, ```'POST'``` requests work just fine, even with larger functions and multiple parameters.

Comment: Yes, you can get it done on the same page without reload/refreshing, just that you need to use AJAX. I  felt that's what you were trying to do by including the 'onChange' eventlistener.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. So AJAX will help me load my python script? Gotta figure out hot to work with it.